# differential equation $y'=\sqrt{|y|(1-y)}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the differential equation
$y'=\sqrt{|y|(1-y)}$ with $y\le1$

I know that $y=0$ and $y=1$ are solutions.

The problem is to compute the general solution for $0<y<1$. On which interval is the solution defined?

I don't know where or how to start. 
$y$ is always positive, so the absolute bars can be left out, but that doesn't seem to make it easier.

Is there anyone who can give me a hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given $$\displaystyle \frac{dy}{dx} = \sqrt{|y|\cdot (1-y)}=\sqrt{y(1-y)}\;,$$ bcz $\; 0<y<1$

So $$\displaystyle \frac{dy}{\sqrt{y(1-y)}} = dx\Rightarrow \int \frac{1}{\sqrt{y(1-y)}}dy = \int dx$$

Now Put $$\displaystyle y=\left(z+\frac{1}{2}\right)\;,$$ Then $dy=dz$

So we get $$\displaystyle \int\frac{1}{\sqrt{\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^2-z^2}}dz = \int dx$$

Now Put $\displaystyle z=\frac{1}{2}\sin \phi\;,$ Then $\displaystyle dz =\frac{1}{2}\cos \phi d\phi $

So we get $$\displaystyle \int\frac{\cos\phi}{\cos \phi}d\phi = \int dx\Rightarrow \phi=x+\mathcal{C}$$

So we get $$\displaystyle \sin^{-1}\left(2z\right) =x+\mathcal{C}$$

So we get $$\displaystyle \sin^{-1}\left(4y-2\right) = x+\mathcal{C}\Rightarrow 4y-2 = \sin(x+\mathcal{C})$$

Comment: I apologize for my comment, I thought it was the same question as discussed before today (and I read a typo in the beginning, you write $y<0<1$, where you probably mean $0<y<1$ of course).

Comment: Sorrryy Mickep I have edited it.

Comment: Thank you very much! The only I don't get is why it is $4y-2$. $z=y-1/2$ right, so shouldn't it be $2y-1$?

Answer (score 0):

The differential is separable, thus you simply need to compute
$$ \int \frac{ dy}{ \sqrt{ y-y^2}} = x + const$$ 
To solve the above, complete the square and use a trig substitution.